# How is the scikit-learn version of Logistic Regression implemented?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I searched a lot, but I couldn't find answers to these questions. Does the scikit-learn's version of Logistic Regression use backpropagation to update the model parameters (slope & bias)? If not how does it fit the line through the data points? In general, I would like to know how the model-based algorithms in scikit-learn learn parameters to fit the data points and how does it differ from the backpropagation technique used in neural networks?

Comment: What have you found based on your own research? A brief description of each solver is listed in [the user guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression), and the sources linked in each solver go directly to research papers or other deep-dive documentation. Which part do you have _specific_ questions about?

Comment: Thank you Anderson, it was really helpful.

Comment: Unless you have specific questions on how to code these things, the question is likely a better fit for the [stats.se] or [datascience.se] stack sites